# How to examine the contents of data returned from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call to a PHP module which returns some HTML.  I want to examine this HTML and extract the data from some custom attributes before considering whether to upload the HTML into the DOM.

I can see the data from the network activity as well as via console.log.  I want to extract the values for the `data-pk` attribute and test them before deciding whether to upload the HTML or just bypass it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./modules/get_recent.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {chat_id:chat_id, chat_name:chat_name, host_id:host_id, host_name:host_name}, // received as a $_POST array
    success: function(data)
    {
       console.log(data);
    },
})
```

and some of the console log data are:

`class="the_pks" data-pk="11"`

`class="the_pks" data-pk="10"`

etc.

In the above data I want to extract and 'have a look at' the numbers 11 and 10.

I just do not know how to extract these `data-pk` values from the returned data from the ajax call. Doing an each on class 'the_pks' does not work as at the time I am looking at the data they have not been loaded into the DOM.

I have searched SO for this but have not come up with an answer.

Any advice will be most appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can always send them separately with the `html`. It would be nice if you could also include `get_recent.php`

Comment: What type of data is the returned `data`? Is it a text string, json or HTML? Including `get_recent.php` should help clarify that.

Comment: Is data returned in JSON format ?

Comment: Here's what's set up in get_recent and then it is just echo'd.$output .= '<li style="border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc">
               <p class="the_pks" data-pk="' . $chat_message_pk . '">' . $from_name . ' - ' . $ze_message . '</p>'
               . '<div align="right"> - <small><em>' . $timer . '</em></small></div>'
               . '</li>';

Comment: I also tried to just alert the response data and all I get is ObjectObject or close to that. Than I tried indexof looking for data-pk but that yielded nothing.

Comment: I don't understand that output at all... I's not html, it's not a string, what's with the dots?

Comment: Hi Victor,  As per my comment below, I have re-engineered this to another way but I sincerely thank you for your interest and comments.  The dots were just an abbreviation of the data that I was trying to interrogate - see above for the full output format. My 'other way' is working perfectly.  'get_recent.php' now does not send the data if they are not needed.  Again, thanks.

Comment: Alright, I'm glad you sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question.
If you get a HTML as a response, you can always create an element and insert that html inside it, without adding it to the DOM. And after that you can search it as you do with a DOM element.

```
const node = document.createElement("div");
//then you can do
node.appendChild(data);
// or
node.innerHTML = data;
```

And after that you can search inside the node:

```
node.querySelectorAll("[data-pk]")
```

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion - I will try it tomorrow - much appreciated.

Comment: I get "TypeError: Argument 1 of node.appendchild is not an object". It is probably just a string but when I tried to search data as a string with indexof it did not work.

Comment: Then I tried   node.innerHTML = data;
       var stuff = node.querySelectorAll("[data-pk]");
       alert(stuff);    that results in [object NodeList] but I don't know what to do with that but any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Then I tried: node.innerHTML = data;
      var stuff = node.querySelectorAll("[data-pk]");
      Array.from(stuff).forEach( el => console.log(el));
      alert("hold it");     and I get a whole lot of <unavailable> messages in the console log. 'Tis a puzzlement to me anyway!

Comment: The following also gives a sequence of <unavailable>      var myNodeList = node.querySelectorAll("[data-pk]");
     for (var i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) 
      {
         var item = myNodeList[i];
       console.log(item);   etc...    P.S., using FireFox 70.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I will re-engineer this - it was probably a clumsy way to try and achieve what I wanted anyway.  Thanks to those who tried to help.